# A comparison of constants and variables in Java and Swift

Tags: java, swift, variables, constants

In Android/Java when I make constants and variables I generally do something like the following:

```
public/private static final int MY_CONSTANT = 73;
int myVariable = 37;
```

And in Swift I do

```
let myConstant: Int = 73
var myVariable: Int = 37
```

or just

```
let myConstant = 73
var myVariable = 37
```

Are the Swift versions equivalent to the Java versions under the hood?

I don't have a specific coding problem right now, but I am trying to gain a deeper understanding of the inner workings of both languages. The question came to mind when I was reading about [Swift properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html). Sometimes making a comparison or having a frame of reference helps me to do that.

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for SO or not. I'll try asking and if it gets too many downvotes I'll delete it.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "under the hood". Programs in Swift are compiled and executed in binary code, while Java code is executed in VM, so you can't say for any process, that they're equals under the hood.

Comment: Good point, @DmitryGinzburg. I guess I am referring to their logic or meaning in terms of object oriented programming. For example, the constant in Java is declared `static` and `final` but its Swift counterpart doesn't have those written in. Ah, ReyCharles just added an answer. This is the type of thing I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `let` in Swift is like specifying `final` in Java, while using `var` in Swift is like leaving out `final` in Java.

Swift also have [Type Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID264) that are global to the type. The keyword for type properties is `static`, so it's exactly the same as in java. If you want a, in java terms, `static final` field then you write `static let`, and if you just want a `static` non-`final` field you write `static var`.

Comment: This is not fully correct. let in swift is a bit more strict than final in java. For example, a final java Set can be added to, but not reassigned. A let swift Set cannot be added to or reassigned- it is entirely immutable.